# Framework project requires Dotnet core runtime

Tags: .net, azure, frameworks

I'm trying to run a .Net Framework 4.8 Azure function project but I'm unable to build it.

When trying to build it says "Error: This Azure Functions project requires .NET Core 4.8 runtime."

How is this possible? Is this somehow dependency related?

Comment: Please show us some (relevant) code or your project file. In its current form, we cannot answer this question. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: what version of the Functions runtime are you using? Only Functions V1.x supports full framework.

Answer (score 2):

As  [rickvdbosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945525/rickvdbosch) suggested we can choose only  the V1 which is the `.Net framework` version .
And after creating we can select the `.net framework` versions according to requirement.

Please refer this for more information MS DOC: [Supported versions in Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2,cmd#supported-versions)   ,  [Azure Functions runtime versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=csharp,v4#visual-studio-runtime-versions)  & GitHub :  [Create Azure Function V1 in VS 2019](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31714)